# how to know which intent opened activity

Tags: android

Hi i'v got two activities going to one activity. When the activity is opened there is a number displayed from either of the two activities

I need to know where the number came from so I can do the appropriate calculations, I think i need an if statement but don't know how to start it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(calculateA.this,
    WAmounts.class);
    intent.putExtra("Result",Total);
    startActivity(intent);


Intent intent = new Intent(CalcB.this,
    WAmounts.class);
    intent.putExtra("ResultB",Total);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Third activiity

```
 Intent sender = getIntent();
    int result = sender.getExtras().getInt("Result");
    answer.setText(result+"");


    int resultB = sender.getExtras().getInt("ResultB");
    answer.setText(resultB+"");

//If number came from first activity  

    a = Integer.parseInt (answer.getText().toString());
    total = (float) (a *x); 
    sd.setText(String.format("%.1f" ,total));



    b = Float.parseFloat (sand.getText().toString());
    total1 = (int)Math.ceil (b*f);
    c.setText(Integer.toString(total1));

  //If number came from second activity     

  a = Integer.parseInt (answer.getText().toString());
  total = (float) (a *x); 
  sd.setText(String.format("%.1f" ,total));



  b = Float.parseFloat (sand.getText().toString());
  total1 = (int)Math.ceil (b*f);
  c.setText(Integer.toString(total1));
```

Comment: "i'v got two activities going to one activity" - what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it some "extras" like shown here: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

```
intent.putExtra("yourLabel", "text1");
```

then in the new activity use

```
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("yourLabel");
}
```

Comment: This is what I do. I create a `"key"` to send called '"source"` and assign a tag that I can easily remember then check what `"source"` is when I get my `Intent` in the receiving `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

since you call your extras "result" and "resultB" you could use sender.hasExtra("result"), and if it returns false - you know which activity started this intent.

Note that bot sender and sender1 in your code get the same intent - the one that started this activity. You don't have to get it twice.